# Need to be cleared in how the code works in python language

Tags: python

I got a small python code but not understand how it works:

```
import xmlrpclib
class PoolTest:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url, allow_none=True)

    def add(self, asset):
        s = asset.marshal()
        self.proxy.add(s)

    def delete(self, asset):
        s = asset.marshal()
        self.proxy.delete(s)
```

I don't understand the way to set these:

self.proxy.add(s)

self.proxy.delete(s)

It looks like recursion but it seems not. Can anybody help me to clear that?

Comment: `self.proxy` is an instance of `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy` class. So basically `self.proxy.add(s)` and `self.proxy.delete(s)` calling the methods of `ServerProxy` class.

Comment: it is not `self.add` it is `self.proxy.add`. There is no recursion here.

Comment: Are you familiar with how Python, in specific classes and attributes, work in general? Are you familiar with using ``self``?

Comment: Hi all, I understand what three you guys said. But there is no method add or delete in class ServerProxy

Comment: the "rpc" part in xmlrpc stands for "remote procedure call". Which procedures are available depends on the server you're connecting to, so of course those cannot be hardcoded in the xlmrpclib. Those are dynamically translated to xmlrpc calls to the server. You can read the source code for more details FWIW - Python is OSS. NB : automagic delegation support in Python is (usually) implemented with the `__getattr__` magic method.